# Angular2 - TypeScript to JavaScript ES6 Syntax - ng2-translate

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2, ng2-translate

I am trying to implement [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) pipe on my Angular2/Ionic2 app which is totally written on JavaScript ES6.

However, I am stuck on a step in the setup phase in which I need to write a piece of code in JavaScript ES6.
What I found so far on their documentation and over the internet is written on TypeScript which throws an Syntax error while trying to implement it on my app.

The code:

```
      @Component({
          template: '<ion-nav swipeBackEnabled="true" [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
        config: {}, 
        providers: [
         {
         //The Syntax error throws on this line, which is needed to be re-written on JS
           provide: TranslateLoader,
           useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
           deps: [Http]
         },
         TranslateService
       ],
       pipes: [TranslatePipe]
      })
```

What I need to know is that how to convert that piece of code written on TypeScript to JavaScript ES6 in order to make it run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the error is... Perhaps it is sufficient to remove the type from your function definition for the attribute useFactory.

```
  @Component({
      template: '<ion-nav swipeBackEnabled="true" [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
    config: {}, 
    providers: [
     {
       provide: TranslateLoader,
       useFactory: (http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
       deps: [Http]
     },
     TranslateService
   ],
   pipes: [TranslatePipe]
  })
```